# VB.NET - Console processes being left open after program exit. How do I close them correctly?

Tags: vb.net, process, dispose

BACKGROUND:

I'm writing a program that opens an interactive console application, listens to STDOUT/STDERR, and sends commands to this interactive session. At the end it will issue an exit command and the process normally goes away. If the user clicks the close button I call dispose on the class which issues the exit command and then attempts to force close the session before the program terminates. I notice that after a day of testing I have a bunch of orphaned processes still running. They build up and never quit. Obviously, I've made a terrible mistake.

QUESTION:

How do I ensure that my console processes are fully dead before my application terminates?

MY DISPOSE METHOD:

```
Protected Overridable Async Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If _disposed Then Return

    If disposing Then
        _handle.Dispose()
        ' Free any other managed objects here.
        '           
        If IsConnected Then Await ClosePort().ConfigureAwait(False)
        If _transmissionCancel IsNot Nothing Then _transmissionCancel.Dispose()           
    End If

    ' Free any unmanaged objects here.
    '
    If _consoleReader IsNot Nothing Then _consoleReader.Dispose()
    If _consoleWriter IsNot Nothing Then _consoleWriter.Dispose()
    If _consoleProcess IsNot Nothing Then _consoleProcess.Dispose()

    _disposed = True
End Sub
```

NOTE:
The "ClosePort" method called here features a kill and a wait:

```
If Not _consoleProcess.WaitForExit(SocketTimeout) Then
    _consoleProcess.Kill()
    _consoleProcess.WaitForExit()
End If
```

Comment: Making Dispose() async is quite unlikely to come to a good end.  The program rarely runs long enough to let the async code complete.

Comment: Unfortunately I am sending exit signals to the process in an async manner. This is supposed to allow the console process to quit on it's own terms. The kill is only for if that fails.

Comment: The async keyword addition had the unfortunate side-effect of programmers no longer knowing how to solve simple async problems.  Start a thread, make sure its IsBackground property isn't False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a suggestion from @hans-passant; I attempted to remove the "Async" modifier from my Dispose method and synchronously wait for the task to complete before completing disposal. I made a task of my function and told it to start. This appears to work but now my program doesn't end when I click the close button. My code jumps from the ".start" to the "End Using" but then the Dispose method stops, passing control back to the UI. If I click close a second time then the dispose method fires again and my program cleanly shuts down.

I post this as an answer because it appears to have solved my original problem and it is my current answer. However, I don't want to mark this as the solution because I have to click close twice to end my program. What have I done?

I am still open to other solutions.

```
Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If _disposed Then Return

    If disposing Then
        _handle.Dispose()
        ' Free any other managed objects here.
        '           
        If IsConnected Then                
            Using holdOnAMinute As Task = Task.Run(Function() ClosePort())                   
                holdOnAMinute.Start()
                holdOnAMinute.Wait(SocketTimeout)
            End Using
        End If
    End If
    ' Free any unmanaged objects here.
    '
    If _consoleReader IsNot Nothing Then _consoleReader.Dispose()
    If _consoleWriter IsNot Nothing Then _consoleWriter.Dispose()
    If _consoleProcess IsNot Nothing Then _consoleProcess.Dispose()
    If _transmissionCancel IsNot Nothing Then _transmissionCancel.Dispose()

    _disposed = True
End Sub
```